# Why won't this OpenLayers map won't display in ReactJS application?

Tags: reactjs, openlayers

Here is the code for my OpenLayers component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { Map, View } from 'ol';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM';

function OpenLayer(props) {
    const [map, setMap] = useState();
    const mapElement = useRef();
    const mapRef = useRef();
    mapRef.current = map;

    useEffect(() => {
        const initialMap = new Map({
            target: 'map',
            layers: [
                new TileLayer({
                    source: new OSM(),
                }),
            ],
            view: new View({
                center: [0, 0],
                zoom: 0,
            }),
        });
        setMap(initialMap);
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            <div ref={mapElement} className="map-container" />
        </div>
    );
}

export default OpenLayer;
```

I am rendering it in my main app like so:

```
    <Row className="mapRow">
        <OpenLayer />
    </Row>
```

I can't seem to get anything to return... Oh, here is my css too:

```
    .mapRow{
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.map-container{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
  }
```

Is there something obvious that I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 3):

Well, you just initialize it in the wrong way. You still initiate the map in the `map` class but you need to initiate it with your current map ref. So you need to use `mapElement` instead of `map` in the initiation phase.

So it should be like this:

```js
const initialMap = new Map({
  target: mapElement.current,
  layers: [
    new TileLayer({
      source: new OSM(),
    }),
  ],
  view: new View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 0,
  }),
});
```

**Working Demo:**

[image: CodeSandbox]

Comment: I really like this solution, I feel like it is the "React Way" of implementing open layers

Comment: So the map state is not required?

Comment: @KirtanDesai You won't need it in this particular case, but later on, you may use it for other purposes like using all the [available methods](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_Map-Map.html) within the `Map` class. So it's better to store it in some variable, it can be a state base on your use case, but it is not necessary to keep it in a state.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you should add at the end of useEffect is
`return () => initialMap.setTarget(null)`. This will free up map resources when the map component unmounts.